# Slider (slide_period) Moving Average Calculation Wrong

Tags: r, slider

I'm trying to use Slider to compute moving averages over some time series data. The data has day resolution (one observation per day). For each observation I want to compute the average daily value over the last 7 days.

The problem is my code is ignoring the missing observations with implied values of zero. So if my period is 7 days, and during some 7 day window there are only 2 observations, it's summing them and dividing by 2, whereas I'm looking to sum and divide by 7 to get the average per day.

In the code below you'll see that the second row (2023-02-03) is computing the average by dividing by 2 (the number of observations), rather than by dividing by 4 (the number of days in the period 2023-01-31 to 2023-02-03).

Is there a *good* way to achieve the desired result, or do I just need to replace the `mean` calculation with `sum() / 7`?

I had originally backfilled the missing observations which worked, but the data is relatively large and quite sparse and doing so massively increased the runtime (from ~8 seconds to ~100).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

data <- data.frame(
  date = Sys.Date() - c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13),
  val = c(0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 10, 0, 1, 1, 6, 1)
)

print(as_tibble(data))

summary <- function(data) {
  summarise(data,
    moving_total = sum(val),
    moving_avg = mean(val, na.rm = FALSE),
    num_observations = n()
  )
}

res <- data %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(
    weekly = slide_period_dfr(
      .x = pick(everything()),
      .i = date,
      .period = "day",
      .f = summary,
      .before = 6,
      .complete = FALSE
    )
  )

print(as_tibble(res))
```

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   date         val
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2023-02-13     0
 2 2023-02-12     0
 3 2023-02-11     2
 4 2023-02-10     1
 5 2023-02-09     0
 6 2023-02-07    10
 7 2023-02-06     0
 8 2023-02-05     1
 9 2023-02-04     1
10 2023-02-03     6
11 2023-01-31     1
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   date         val weekly$moving_total $moving_avg $num_observations
   <date>     <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>             <int>
 1 2023-01-31     1                   1        1                    1
 2 2023-02-03     6                   7        3.5                  2
 3 2023-02-04     1                   8        2.67                 3
 4 2023-02-05     1                   9        2.25                 4
 5 2023-02-06     0                   9        1.8                  5
 6 2023-02-07    10                  18        3.6                  5
 7 2023-02-09     0                  18        3                    6
 8 2023-02-10     1                  13        2.17                 6
 9 2023-02-11     2                  14        2.33                 6
10 2023-02-12     0                  13        2.17                 6
11 2023-02-13     0                  13        2.17                 6
```

Just a note on the implementation. In the real world the moving averages are being computed over groups, hence the use of `pick(everything())` above. Don't think it's necessary for the toy example, but I leave it in just in case it influences the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution is to supply zero values for the absent dates.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

(data_ <- tibble(
  date = Sys.Date() - c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13),
  val = c(0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 10, 0, 1, 1, 6, 1)
))


summary <- function(.data) {
  summarise(.data,
    moving_total = sum(val),
    moving_avg = mean(val, na.rm = FALSE),
    num_observations = n()
  )
}

(full_dates <- tibble(date=
  seq(min(data_$date),
    max(data_$date),
    by = "1 day"
  )))

(fdj <- left_join(
  full_dates,
  data_
) |> mutate(val = if_else(
                    is.na(val), 0, val
)))

(res <-
  mutate(fdj,
    weekly = slide_period_dfr(
      .x = pick(everything()),
      .i = date,
      .period = "day",
      .f = summary,
      .before = 6,
      .complete = FALSE
    )
  ))
```